# DT proxy displays no data

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am having problems with the app I am trying to build. I have a large data table (portion shown below) that I am trying to filter based on user inputs. The side panel allows the user to select the gauge(s), date range, and then the desired columns (i.e. precip and temp). If the column checkbox is selected, then the filter options display, allowing the rows to be filtered. Once the user clicks the submit button, the table should render based on all the chosen inputs. The entire data table renders when I load the app but once I chose filters and then click submit, the table output shows "No data available in table" "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries." There should be data displaying since the values I try are within it. Perhaps I shouldn't be using a proxy table to filter? I don't want the table to update every time the filters are changed (since its a large dataset), just when the submit button is pressed. Any help would be appreciated.

```r
# load libraries
library(tidyverse)  
library(DT)
library(rgdal)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) #shiny java script with R language
library(here)

# import dataset
allvarsdata = readRDS(here("Scripts/shiny app/allvarsdata.RDS")) #datatable
varsdata = as_tibble(allvarsdata)

A tibble: 6 x 4
  GaugeID     DATE          PRCP  TAIR   
  <chr>     <date>       <dbl>  <dbl> 
1 01013500   1980-10-01    3.1    3.1   
2 01435762   1980-10-02    4.24  10.5 
3 01837490   1980-10-03    8.02  11.8  
4 02947591   1980-10-04   15.3    7.38 
5 03048601   1980-10-05    8.48   4.8 
6 09385031   2014-12-06    0      5.41 



###############################################
ui = fluidPage(
  # implement shiny js features
  useShinyjs(), 
  titlePanel(),  
  tabsetPanel(        
    tabPanel(title = "Data",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 # gauge selection, pull down with all 671 gauges        
                 selectInput(inputId = "gauge1", label = "Select USGS Gauge(s)", 
                             choices = sort(unique(allvarsdata$GaugeID)), 
                             selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),  
               
                 # two buttons to 1) select all gauges and 2) clear the selections  
                 fluidRow(
                   column(width = 6, actionButton("selectall", "Select all")),
                   column(width = 6, actionButton("clear", "Clear"))
                 ), #fluidRow close
     
# date range selection for entire record
                 dateRangeInput(inputId = "daterange", label = "Select date range", 
                                start = "1981-01-01", end = "2014-12-31", 
                                min = "1981-01-01", max = "2014-12-31",
                                format = "yyyy-mm-dd", separator = " - "), 
                
 # checkbox to select precipitation column          
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "prcp", label = "Precipitation", value = FALSE),  
                 conditionalPanel( #display slider when box checked, filter rows based on slider
                   condition = "input.prcp",
                   sliderInput(inputId = "prcp1", label = "mm/day", 
                                      min = 0, max = 200, value = c(50, 100), ticks = FALSE)),
            
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "temp", label = "Temperature", value = FALSE),
                  conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.temp",
                  sliderInput(inputId = "temp1", label = "Celcius", 
                                      min = -45,  max = 40, value = c(0, 20), ticks = FALSE)), 
                 
              # submit button to filter/select data based on all user inputs, only when clicked            
                actionButton(inputId = "submit1", 
                              label = "Submit")
             
                   ), #sidebarPanel close
                 
              mainPanel(
               DT::DTOutput(outputId = "filteredtable")
                 
               ) #mainPanel close 
       )  # sidebarLayout close               
    ), #tabPanel close
   ) # tabsetPanel close   
) # fluidPage close

### SERVER ###

server = function(input, output, session) {
  # create reactive values based on allvarsdata 
  filtered = reactiveValues(fdat = varsdata)
  
  output$filteredtable = DT::renderDT({
   isolate(filtered$fdat)   # render DT with no dependency between data and render function
  }, options = list(paging = TRUE, processing = TRUE))
    
  proxy = DT::dataTableProxy("filteredtable") #updates data instead of using render function
  observe({
   DT::replaceData(proxy, filtered$fdat)
  })
    
 observeEvent(input$submit1, {     #wrap all filters within the submit action button
     filtered$fdat = filtered$fdat %>% 
     dplyr::filter(GaugeID == input$gauge1,
                  DATE >= input$daterange[1], DATE <= input$daterange[2], 
                  PRCP >= input$prcp1[1], PRCP <= input$prcp1[2],  
                  TAIR >= input$temp1[1], TAIR <= input$temp1[2]) 
                 
# if no gauge is selected, return no results      
      if(is.null(input$gauge1)) {
           return(NULL)
       }
     if(is.null(input$prcp)) { # if precip box is not checked, remove precip column     
       filtered$fdat = filtered$fdat %>% 
         select(-PRCP)
            }
     if(is.null(input$temp)) {  # if temp box is not checked, remove temp column from data table    
       filtered$fdat = filtered$fdat %>% 
         select(-TAIR)
     }  
     
    filtered$fdat
     
   }) #observeEvent close (submit)
  
    # clear selected gauges button based on shinyjs reset function      
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    reset("gauge1")
  })
 
  # select all gauges button 
  observeEvent(input$selectall, {
    if(input$selectall) {
      updateSelectInput(session = session, "gauge1",
                        selected = varsdata$GaugeID) 
    }
  })
      
} # server close bracket

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few issues here while filtering.

1. Your dates are character
2. Variable `input$prcp` and `input$temp` are logical
3. filtering was being performed even when the variables did not exist (for `temp1` and `prcp1`)

Once you fix these issues, you don't need proxy as your object is a `reactiveValues` object.  Try this

```
varsdata <- read.table(text="GaugeID     DATE          PRCP  TAIR 
1 01013500   1980-10-01    3.1    3.1   
2 01435762   1980-10-02    4.24  10.5 
3 01837490   1980-10-03    8.02  11.8  
4 02947591   1980-10-04   15.3    7.38 
5 03048601   1980-10-05    8.48   4.8 
6 09385031   2014-12-06    0      5.41",  header=T)

allvarsdata <- varsdata

###############################################
ui = fluidPage(
  # implement shiny js features
  useShinyjs(), 
  #titlePanel(),  
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",      
    tabPanel(title = "Data", 
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 # gauge selection, pull down with all 671 gauges        
                 selectInput(inputId = "gauge1", label = "Select USGS Gauge(s)", 
                             choices = sort(unique(allvarsdata$GaugeID)), 
                             selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),  
                 
                 # two buttons to 1) select all gauges and 2) clear the selections  
                 fluidRow(
                   column(width = 6, actionButton("selectall", "Select all")),
                   column(width = 6, actionButton("clear", "Clear"))
                 ), #fluidRow close
                 
                 # date range selection for entire record
                 dateRangeInput(inputId = "daterange", label = "Select date range", 
                                start = "1980-01-01", end = "2014-12-31", 
                                min = "1980-01-01", max = "2014-12-31",
                                format = "yyyy-mm-dd", separator = " - "), 
                 
                 # checkbox to select precipitation column          
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "prcp", label = "Precipitation", value = FALSE),  
                 conditionalPanel( #display slider when box checked, filter rows based on slider
                   condition = "input.prcp",
                   sliderInput(inputId = "prcp1", label = "mm/day", 
                               min = 0, max = 200, value = c(0, 100), ticks = FALSE)),
                 
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "temp", label = "Temperature", value = FALSE),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.temp",
                   sliderInput(inputId = "temp1", label = "Celcius", 
                               min = -45,  max = 40, value = c(0, 20), ticks = FALSE)), 
                 
                 # submit button to filter/select data based on all user inputs, only when clicked            
                 actionButton(inputId = "submit1",  label = "Submit")
                 
               ), #sidebarPanel close
               
               mainPanel(
                 DTOutput(outputId = "filteredtable")
                 
               ) #mainPanel close 
             )  # sidebarLayout close               
    ) #tabPanel close
  ) # tabsetPanel close   
) # fluidPage close

### SERVER ###

server = function(input, output, session) {
  # create reactive values based on allvarsdata 
  filtered = reactiveValues(fdat = varsdata)
  
  output$filteredtable = renderDT({
    filtered$fdat  # render DT with no dependency between data and render function
  }, options = list(paging = TRUE, processing = TRUE))
  
  # proxy = DT::dataTableProxy("filteredtable") #updates data instead of using render function
  # observe({
  #   DT::replaceData(proxy, filtered$fdat)
  # })
  
  fdata <- eventReactive(input$submit1, {     
    # if no gauge is selected, return no results      
    if(is.null(input$gauge1)) {
      filteredt <- NULL
    }else{
      filteredt = varsdata %>% 
        dplyr::filter(GaugeID %in% input$gauge1, as.Date(DATE) >= as.Date(input$daterange[1]), as.Date(DATE) <= as.Date(input$daterange[2]))
      if(input$prcp) { # if precip box is not checked, remove precip column
        filteredt = filteredt %>% dplyr::filter(PRCP >= input$prcp1[1], PRCP <= input$prcp1[2])
      } else {
        filteredt = filteredt %>% select(-PRCP)
      }

      if(input$temp) {  # if temp box is not checked, remove temp column from data table
        filteredt = filteredt %>% dplyr::filter(TAIR >= input$temp1[1], TAIR <= input$temp1[2])
      }else {
        filteredt = filteredt %>% select(-TAIR)
      }
    }
    
    filteredt
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit1, { 
    filtered$fdat <- fdata()
  }) #observeEvent close (submit)
  
  # clear selected gauges button based on shinyjs reset function      
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    reset("gauge1")
  })
  
  # select all gauges button 
  observeEvent(input$selectall, {
    if(input$selectall) {
      updateSelectInput(session = session, "gauge1",
                        selected = varsdata$GaugeID) 
    }
  })
  
} # server close bracket

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Just one question, what is the purpose of the DTOutput("t1") addition in the UI?

Comment: You can ignore it.  I used it while testing.